# Angular 4 - Toggle Switch to detect status

Tags: angular

I am using the library toggle-switch:
[Toogle Switch](https://ghinda.net/css-toggle-switch/)

This my switch element:

```
<label class="switch-light switch-material">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <strong class="large-4 columns float-left">
        Off
    </strong>
    <span class="large-4 columns float-left">
        <span>Off</span>
        <span>On</span>
        <a (click)="detectStatus(true or false)"></a>
    </span>
    <strong class="large-4 columns float-left">
        On
    </strong>
</label>
```

Using the function detectStatus(), I want to send as parameter value false if the status is Off and true if the status is On.

How could do it? thanks,

Comment: use `[ngModel]` and `[ngChecked]`

Comment: Thanks, simply passing a boolean and works, this.isOn = !this.isOn;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ngModel` and `checked` in input to achieve this

Try this

```
<input [ngModel]="test" [checked]="test" type="checkbox" (change) = "checkClicked(test)">
```

In Component:

```
    checkClicked(val){
        this.test = !val;       
    }
```

Here is the working [**plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/IIm66ooCKYFLKpIMQZtT?p=preview)